# How can I access UserId in ASP.NET Membership without using Membership.GetUser()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership

How can I access `UserId` in ASP.NET Membership without using `Membership.GetUser(username)` in ASP.NET Web Application Project?

Can `UserId` be included in `Profile` namespace next to `UserName` (`System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase`)?

Comment: Can you expand on the reason why?

Comment: When I call Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey everytime is maked call to DB to retrieve this UserId

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to write authentication of users users on my own (very simple but it works) and I should done this long time ago.

My original question was about UserId and it is not available from:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Following up on your post, if you import using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity; you will have access to User.Identity.GetUserId()

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
Response.Write("CurrentUser ID :: " + CurrentUser.ProviderUserKey);
```

Comment: Passing in the username certainly helps, as otherwise I was getting null back!  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 13):

Is your reason for this to save a database call everytime you need the UserId? If so, when I'm using the ASP.NET MembershipProvider, I usually either do a custom provider that allows me to cache that call, or a utility method that I can cache.

If you're thinking of putting it in the Profile, I don't see much reason for doing so, especially as it also will still require a database call and unless you are using a custom profile provider there, it has the added processing of parsing out the UserId.

If you're wondering why they did not implement a GetUserId method, it's simply because you're not always guaranteed that that user id will be a GUID as in the included provider.

EDIT:

See [ScottGu's article on providers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx) which provides a [link to downloading the actual source code for i.e. SqlMembershipProvider](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/3/ab3c284b-dc9a-473d-b7e3-33bacfcc8e98/ProviderToolkitSamples.msi).

But the simplest thing to do really is a GetUserId() method in your user object, or utility class, where you get the UserId from cache/session if there, otherwise hit the database, cache it by username (or store in session), and return it.

For something more to consider (but be very careful because of cookie size restrictions): [Forms Auth: Membership, Roles and Profile with no Providers and no Session](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/33d4018a-03cf-48aa-9b68-82ba27aa6af9/forms-auth-membership-r.aspx)

Comment: Nice little article at the end of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public string GetUserID()
            {
                MembershipUser _User;
                string _UserId = "";
                _User = Membership.GetUser();
                Guid UserId = (Guid)_User.ProviderUserKey;
                return _UserId = UserId.ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1) Use username as the primary key for your user data table
i.e:

```
select * from [dbo.User] where Username = 'andrew.myhre'
```

2) Add UserID to the profile.

There are pros and cons to each method. Personally I prefer the first, because it means I don't necessarily need to set up the out-of-the-box profile provider, and I prefer to enforce unique usernames in my systems anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew: I'd be careful of doing a query like what you've shown as by default, there's no index that matches with that so you run the risk of a full table scan. Moreover, if you're using your users database for more than one application, you haven't included the application id.

The closest index is aspnet_Users_Index which requires the ApplicationId and LoweredUserName.

EDIT:

Oops - reread Andrew's post and he's not doing a select * on the aspnet_Users table, but rather, a custom profile/user table using the username as the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`? (Make sure to verify that `User` and `Identity` are non-null first.)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
MembershipUser m = Membership.GetUser();
Response.Write("ID: " + m.ProviderUserKey.ToString());
}
```

Will give you the UserID (uniqueidentifier) for the current user from the aspnet_Membership table - providing the current has successfully logged in. If you try to <%= %> or assign that value before a successful authentication you will get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1169200&page=1

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, the solution is in the web.config configuration, try configuring web.config with these:

```
 <roleManager
             enabled="true"
             cacheRolesInCookie="true"
             defaultProvider="QuickStartRoleManagerSqlProvider"
             cookieName=".ASPXROLES"
             cookiePath="/"
             cookieTimeout="30"
             cookieRequireSSL="false"
             cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
             createPersistentCookie="false"
             cookieProtection="All">
  <providers>
    <add name="QuickStartRoleManagerSqlProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
        connectionStringName="ASPNETDB"
        applicationName="SecurityQuickStart"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

internally it's executing below script in `sql server`

```
select * from vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers where USERNAME like '%username%'
```