# Secure folder and authentication

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I am going to create a website which in that, users can create their own album of pictures and upload them on the website. I am going to use ASP.NET (C#) to develop this website.
Each user only has access to the set of images which is dedicated to that user no shared items are permitted, so users should have their own username and password and log in before getting to their album.
So I have 2 question, where should pictures get stored to have prefect access control and restriction.
What is the best secure way to authenticate users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply upload that file, and add a record that represents the user's UserId, and the path to the image.

Or you can upload directly to Sql Server 2008's (can you use that) FileStream object to store the images - and still have a record that links it to the user's UserId

To authenticate users just use the MembershipProvider. They will have a user id associated with their login. That becomes your key to look up the images.

You can get their name or user id in different ways. See:
[How can I access UserId in ASP.NET Membership without using Membership.GetUser()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146896/how-to-access-userid-in-asp-net-membership-without-using-membership-getuser)
for more details on getting the Id (via ProviderUserKey)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then is it acceptable to upload the images to the SQL server images do have huge file and there are many of them, is it the best way to keep data like images?!
 Actually I’m just wondering if I supposed to put images in folder (not the base) should they be in a folder  under httpdocs folder or not. Since the content in that folder (httpdocs) is accessible through the URL, I don how I can apply security setting to the folder?

Comment: The ways I'm recommending to upload to SQL only point to a file and aren't actually stored on SQL server. Put then in a folder either outside of the application or a folder in the application that is not directly accessible. You can control this folder in your web.config authorization rules. Then you can Response.WriteFile the file to the client.