# Retrieve User from LDAP using ASP Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

My company is using LDAP to authenticate its users. I have the logging in portion working but now I need a way that once logged in we can refer to the user. I have tried multiple ways and none of them are working.

Here is the code I am using to log in:

```
var x = Membership.Provider;

if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        string userId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

On this line:

```
string userId = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

I am getting an error:

> The parameter 'username' must not be empty.

I have also tried a few options from here:

[How can I access UserId in ASP.NET Membership without using Membership.GetUser()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146896/how-can-i-access-userid-in-asp-net-membership-without-using-membership-getuser)

Like this one:

```
MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

which I get the same error

For anyone wondering, iamtooamazing suggested below:

```
string userId = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName).ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

That would work in this method.  However, I will not be able to use that anywhere else in the solution.  I need something that will work in all the controllers (and methods in them)

Using this code:

```
string user = ((CustomIdentity)User.Identity).UserId;
```

I am receiving this error on that line:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity' to type
>   'STCAuthentication.Models.CustomIdentity'.

This is the current state of my code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var x = Membership.Provider;
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                string user = ((CustomIdentity)User.Identity).UserId;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: why can't you just do: string userId = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName).ProviderUserKey.ToString();?

Comment: @iamtooamazing but that will only work within this method.  What would I do in any other place in my solution?

Comment: @iamtooamazing do you have any idea?

Comment: @djblois are you already authenticated when you try to cast the Identity?

Comment: @SílvioN., yes I am already authenticated

Comment: @djblois well you are setting your customidentity in global.asax, at this point you havent done any kind of http request for it to be settled. if you want to get the userid in this point, you will have to use Membership.GetUser(model.UserName).ProviderUserKey.ToString();
you'll be able to use ((CustomIdentity)User.Identity).UserId; after the first redirect when you login.

Comment: Silvio, I am doing my first redirect and put this code in the method that I redirected to string name = ((CustomIdentity)User.Identity).Name;

Comment: @SílvioN. however I am still getting the error on that line. even after my first redirect.

Answer (score 0):

> That would work in this method. However, I will not be able to use
>   that anywhere else in the solution. I need something that will work in
>   all the controllers (and methods in them)

What about if you create a custom identity that stores your userid?

```
public class CustomIdentity : IIdentity
{
    private IIdentity Identity { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; private set; }

    public string AuthenticationType { get { return Identity.AuthenticationType; } }
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get { return Identity.IsAuthenticated; } }
    public string Name { get { return Identity.Name; } }

    public CustomIdentity(IIdentity identity)
    {
        Identity = identity;
        UserId = Membership.GetUser(identity.Name).ProviderUserKey.ToString();
    }
}
```

Create a CustomPrincipal as well,

```
public class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    private IPrincipal Principal;
    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }
    public bool IsInRole(string role) { return Principal.IsInRole(role); }

    public CustomPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
    {
        Principal = principal;
        //this force the load of the userid
        Identity = new CustomIdentity(principal.Identity);
    }
}
```

Then in Global.asax just set

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var principal = new CustomPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User);
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
}
```

And you can access your UserId like this

```
((CustomIdentity)User.Identity).UserId //In Controllers
((CustomIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).UserId //Inside classes
```

Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Looks very close. What about when using [Authorize(Roles = "Client, Administrator")]?

Comment: what about now? it's now passed the default principal to the contructor so that the principal object uses the native IsInRole method...

Comment: Thank you, I am going to work through this and get back to you.

Comment: But if i'm not wrong, the usage of [Authorize] attribute will use your default/custom RoleProvider, it will not interfere with the customprincipal or the customidentity...

Comment: Hi Silvio, I have updated it with the error I am receiving.

Comment: Silvio, I am going to give you the bounty for all your help - instead of you losing it.  I do hope you can continue to help me get it working after though. Ty for all your help.

Comment: @djblois Just in this specific action (Login), replace the string user = ((CustomIdentity)User.Identity).UserId; for string user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName).ProviderUserKey.ToString(); because your custom identity is still not defined.

Comment: Silvio that works I am trying after the page is redirected I am getting that error.